# Append text to richTextBox1

Tags: visual-c++

What is simplest way to append text to richTextBox1?

Also I found that to set it from std::string is not very simple

```
richTextBox1->Text= gcnew String ( str.c_str() ) ;
```

How to deal with these operations in everyday life?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try:

```
String str = "12345";
richTextBox1->Text += str;
```